How to access GitLab CI/CD secure file from Python script?
I have a question regarding GitLab's Secure Files feature in the CI/CD configuration. I’ve successfully added GitLab Secure File into my YAML configuration (and confirmed with ls-lah showing the file in the output, however I’m having trouble with accessing the secure file from within my Python script.
I'm not super familiar with Docker but I wonder if this file is located in the container somehow. In the YAML config, my secure file lives within a folder named test-folder so in my Python script, I tried the following:
with open('test-folder/file_name', "rb") as key:

However in my pipeline output it’s showing this error:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test-folder/file_name'

Any ideas on how I can access my secure file? Any help is appreciated!

Did you download the secure file before using it?
